# Расчёт плоской проекции из широты и долготы (EPSG:3857)

Tags: c#, карты, openstreetmap

Получаю данные широты и долготы с OSM, решил нарисовать на плоскости, предварительно возводя в 3 степень, возле себя всё хорошо, за сотни километров - карта начинает искажаться. Далее я начал искать формулы для проекции на плоскость и обратно, вот что нашёл и подстроил под свой проект:

```
    const float POS_CONST = 20037508.34f; // Эта константа в итоге должна перевести градусы в метры
    const float ZOOM_CONST = 0.005f; // Этой константой я масштабирую точки, чтобы "сжать" плоскую карту до нужного мне размера

    public static float GetUnityPointX(float lon) // Получение пространственной координаты по широте
    {
        return (lon * POS_CONST * ZOOM_CONST / 180f);
    }

    public static float GetUnityPointY(float lat) // Получение пространственной координаты по долготе
    {
        var y = Mathf.Log(Mathf.Tan((90 + lat) * Mathf.PI / 360)) / (Mathf.PI / 180);
        return (y * POS_CONST * ZOOM_CONST / 180f);
    }

    public static float GetOsmPointX(float x) // Получение OSM широты по мировой координате
    {
        return x / (Mathf.PI / 180.0f) / POS_CONST / ZOOM_CONST;
    }

    public static float GetOsmPointY(float y) // Получение OSM долготы по мировой координате
    {
        return (2f * Mathf.Atan(Mathf.Exp(y / POS_CONST / ZOOM_CONST)) - Mathf.PI / 2f) / (Mathf.PI / 180f);
    }
```

Формулы взял отсюда: https://gist.github.com/springmeyer/871897

В итоге, картинка выравнилась по X (ну, потому что избавились от степенной зависимости), и немного выравнилась по Y, но, искажения остались.

Что происходит теперь - я делю мир по высоте на равные части (делю градусы на константу), далее перевожу градусы этих точек в мировые координаты. (деля мир на константу по X и на константу по Y я получаю сетку из прямоугольников одинаковой длины - такой прямоугольник существует в градусах, так же, такой прямоугольник я рассчитываю в координатах мира в виде плоской проекции).

Возьмём за размер прямоугольника некий 1 градус. Это значит что в любой точке земли может быть прямоугольник размера 1x1 виртуальный градус. Вот я нарисую прямоугольник и его проекцию на плоскость:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Справа этот прямоугольник в градусах, слева после того как я спроецировал его на плоскость по формулам.

Далее, я начинаю двигать прямоугольник в градусах ближе к полюсу, вот что в итоге получается:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обращу внимание ещё раз - размер прямоугольников одинаков в градусах, но отличается после того как я выполняю проекцию.

Вот проекция Меркатора:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь так же видно что у экватора прямоугольники более менее одинаковы, но чем ближе к полюсам, тем они сильнее вытягиваются, ровно то что происходит у меня.

Что я хочу получить в итоге:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Правильно ли я вообще понимаю концепцию широты, долготы?
2. Есть ли алгоритмы проекции на плоскость, которые бы гарантировали мне что взятый интервал в градусах по широте будет всегда одинаков, так же как и получаемый в расчётах интервал между точками в мире? И что в моём алгоритме неправильно?

Comment: Если честно, не совсем понял что вы имеете в виду, по описанию похоже
[проекцию Plate Carrée](https://proj.org/operations/projections/eqc.html). А вы смотрели существующие проекции? Их [полный список](https://proj.org/operations/projections/index.html) и самые известные описаны в [википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9)

Comment: Извиняюсь, сначала прочитал вопрос, а потом уже посмотрел на заголовок. Получается, вам нужна [проекция Web-merkator](https://proj.org/operations/projections/webmerc.html). А почему вы ее вручную считаете? У Proj4 вроде должен быть биндинг и на C#.

Comment: @DiD, Не совсем понял вопроса... У меня есть lon/lat, по ним я запрашиваю карту, по ним позиционируется устройство, и по ним я работаю с миром - например, ограничиваю персонажа в перемещении, помещая его в окружность, центр которого - координаты устройства. Но сам мир - у меня в виде обычных метровых координат, поэтому приходится все градусы переводить в мировые точки, а так как ряд действий в мире может сказываться на карте - мировые координаты надо уметь переводить в исходные градусы lon/lat.

Comment: Суть вопроса - есть ли алгоритмы, которые разворачивают сферу так, чтобы в любой точке сферы взятый прямоугольник в градусах перемещаемый по сфере, и проецируемый на плоскость не искажался от позиции на сфере.

Comment: проекция Plate Carrée - как раз представляет сферу как цилиндр, а карта - в  форме рулона, положение на карте легко связать с координатами (пропорционально), но чем ближе к северу и к югу, тем сильнее карта растянута по отношению к километру вдоль долготы и потому не юзабильна.

Comment: Кстати, Проекция Ламберта возможно тоже подошла бы https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB:Lambert_cylindrical_equal-area_projection_SW.jpg   схематично https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cb/Tissot_indicatrix_world_map_Lambert_cyl_equal-area_proj.svg/2560px-Tissot_indicatrix_world_map_Lambert_cyl_equal-area_proj.svg.png

Comment: @DiD, Это то что мне нужно, пожалуйста, добавьте ответ со списком проекций, и отдельно упоминание о равновеликой азимутальной проекции Ламберта, кажется, это полностью решает мою проблему!

Comment: Вот это описание со схемами как делается проекция очень понятно обьясняет https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%9B%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0

Comment: Так же подходит описание о  равновеликой цилиндрической проекции Ламберта

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131775/discussion-between-did-and-test123).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем перенесу итоги обсуждений здесь в ответе.
Начну с ссылок списков проекций, где надо было искать в первую очередь. То есть, все проекции уже давно спроектированы, изобретать свою формулу надо после изучения всех существующих:

- [Список проекций из документации `Proj4`](https://proj.org/operations/projections/index.html) (на английском языке).
- [Список проекций на Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9) (на русском языке).

Из обсуждений выяснилось что автор изначально искал [Равновеликую цилиндрическую проекцию Ламберта](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%9B%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0).

[image: Равновеликая цилиндрическая проекция Ламберта (с) Википедия]

Но, как я предполагал изначально, автору не нужны были все эти проекции,
если хорошо подумать. В общем,  конкретно в данной ситуации, нужный функционал полностью реализуется библиотекой коммерческого проекта [mapbox.com](https://mapbox.com). У mapbox есть множество [опенсурсных проектов](https://github.com/mapbox). Некоторые из проектов задевают какие-то проприетарные сервисы.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!